# How to get all the rowIndex's of selected

Tags: google-apps-script

With the new sheets it allows you to now select non-adjacent rows and columns.    I would like to be able to capture to an array all the selected rows indexes.   How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this at the moment or to obtain the selected ranges from a script.
A request is pending and you can support it here : https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4056
by adding a star to the request.